# How to create seperate variables in a .csv file derived from values in text files?

Tags: csv, unix, awk, text-files

I would be grateful for any advice you could provide on how to run the following in the UNIX command line. Essentially, I have text files for each of my subjects, which look like the following (simulated data).

```
2.97    3.61    -1.88
-0.38   2.33    -0.22
0.76    -0.71   -0.97
```

The subject ID is contained in the textfile heading (e.g. '100012_var.txt')

I would like to write a .csv file where each value (for each subject) in a row appears under a new variable heading. For instance:

```
ID      Var1   Var2     Var3      Var4    Var5    Var6    Var7    Var8    Var9
100012  2.97    3.61    -1.88   -0.38   2.33    -0.22   0.76    -0.71   -0.97
100013  -1.21   1.79    -0.88   -0.91   2.01    2.88    0.32    -1.15   2.70
```

I would also like to ensure this is consistent across all subjects, i.e. value 1 in row 1 is always coded VAR 1.

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -v RS="" -v OFS="\t" '              # using whole file as a record *
NR==1 {                                   # first record, build the header
    printf "ID" OFS
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf "Var%d%s",i,(i<NF?OFS:ORS)
}
{
    split(FILENAME,f,"_")                 # split filename by _ to get the number
    $1=$1                                 # rebuild the record to use tabs (OFS)
    print f[1],$0                         # print number part and the values
}' 100012_var.txt 100013_var.txt          # them files
```

Output:

```
ID      Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6    Var7    Var8    Var9
100012  2.97    3.61    -1.88   -0.38   2.33    -0.22   0.76    -0.71   -0.97
100013  -1.21   1.79    -0.88   -0.91   2.01    2.88    0.32    -1.15   2.70
```

* `-v RS=""` explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, James! How would you translate the output of your script to a .csv file?

Comment: Just redirect the output to a new file, ilke `awk ... > output_file.tsv`

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and perl

```
mlr --n2x --ifs ' ' --repifs put '$file=FILENAME' then reorder -f file input.tsv | \
perl -p -e 's/^\r\n$//g' | \
mlr --n2c --ifs ' ' --repifs uniq -a then cut -f 2 then cat -n then reshape -s n,2 \
then rename 1,ID then rename -r '([0-9]+),VAR\1'
```

you will have (it's a CSV)

```
ID,VAR2,VAR3,VAR4,VAR5,VAR6,VAR7,VAR8,VAR9,VAR10
input.tsv,2.97,3.61,-1.88,-0.38,2.33,-0.22,0.76,-0.71,-0.97
```

Then you can do a for loop for all files.